# Prove that $\mathbb{N}$ is not metrizable where $U$ is open if it is $U=\mathbb{N}$, $U = \emptyset$, or $\mathbb{N}$ \ $U$ is a finite subset.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

$\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers.

Any set $U$ is open if it is $U=\mathbb{N}$, $U = \emptyset$, or $\mathbb{N}$ \ $U$ is a finite subset.

This defines a topology on $\mathbb{N}$.

Prove that $\mathbb{N}$ is not metrizable (there is no metrics on $\mathbb{N}$ that gives rise to the topology)

Comment: What are some properties you know a metric space has? Does $\mathbb{N}$ with the cofinite topology have all of them?

Comment: @DanielFischer hmmm... the open sets under a metric define topology?

Comment: @Dosomemaths Yes. That's how you define metrizability, if there is some metric that generates the topology of the space.

Comment: @SantiagoC Ah yes. A topological space is metrizable if there is some metric such that the open sets under the metric is equal to the set of open sets in topological space.

Comment: @SantiagoC Can I say that there exists an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ such that it is closed under the metric?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick to solving these kind of problems (most of the time) is to think of a property that one kind of space meets but the other doesn't. In this case, as Daniel Fischer said, think of something that metrizable spaces meet but that the natural numbers with the cofinite topology don't.

In this case, there are MANY things that fail. We can start simple. For example, think of the Hausdorff property.

Comment: What is Hausdorff propert..?

Comment: That for every two distinct points $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ there are neighborhoods $U,V$ such that $n \in U$, $m \in V$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$.

Comment: And $U$ and $V$ have to be open right?

Comment: All metric spaces has Hausdorff property but natural numbers with cofinite topology does not!